# Regex to extract img source from a string

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing

I have strings like this:

```
<img width="1" height="1" alt="" src="http://row.bc.yahoo.com.link">
```

What regex should I have to write in C# to extract src portion of it ? (end result should be "http://row.bc.yahoo.com.link" )

Comment: What have you come up with until now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are dealing with HTML you're better of using a HTML parser like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Sample:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(
    "<img width=\"1\" height=\"1\" alt=\"\" src=\"http://row.bc.yahoo.com.link\">");

var anchor = doc.DocumentNode.Element("img");

Console.WriteLine(anchor.Attributes["src"].Value);
```

---

**Update:**
If you are already using the HTML agility pack and have selected all the `img` tags from the document using XPath you need to iterate them and access the `src` attribute:

```
var imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@src");

foreach (var node in imgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
}
```

Comment: I use Agillity Pack and use XPath to select nodes that match //img/@src. But once I have that I want to extract the src from that node. I cannot do that using but regex.

Comment: You are right, there is no need to use regex as I already have the node obtained with Agillity Pack.

Answer (score 3):

This pattern should work: `src="([^"]*)"`.

Comment: it works, but the solution provided when using HTML Agility Pack is best. Tnx